# When picking up a girl in French (or other countries), is it proper to use formal or informal speech?

Tags: vouvoiement

Like, do you use tu or vous in this situation for your wording? Does it matter if you are trying to be more respectful or formal if you see a girl and are using lines to get a date with her?

Comment: Can you precise if you're young and if you know this girl ? If you know her what is your current relationship ?

Comment: You don't know her. You just met in a bar/cafe and are attempting to speak with her to introduce yourself and get to know her. And the age would be contemporary, for the most part, with the purpose of dating. So, while a 60 year old may be hitting on an 20 year old, I'm speaking more of someone within your own age range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case you describe, "tu" would be far more common. Bar/cafe are places you're in to relax. Most of the time, even waiters will use "tu" even if they don't know you.

"Vous" is formal and would not be used by most of the people, unless they want to seem lordy. An exception might be older people who might prefer to be "vouvoyées", even by people of their age.

People very lordy and/or old can even call each other "vous" even if they are married, like former French president Jacques Chirac and his wife Bernadette do.